# Apply opacity to background image via selector

Tags: css

I want a `background-image` to have less opacity in current state and increase opacity on `hover`. The attributes should be assigned via selectors (as I have many classes) in CSS as I can't access the HTML code.

For some reason my code doesn't work (on `hover` the opacity should be 1) - please see my snippet below.

Would anyone know what the problem could be?

Many thanks

David

```css
[class*=subcategory] {
  background-size: 20px !important;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

[class*=subcategory]:hover span {
  background-size: 20px !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.subcategory1:hover span {
  background-size: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="subcategory1">
  <span style="font-size: 100px; background-image: url(https://designmodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/designmodo-icon.png); background-size: 25px">I am in a mess</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You have first opacity set on the div, and second set on span, that causes issue, put it on the same element and see.

Comment: @Stickers Just tried and that indeed worked!! Thank you very much Stickers, that was very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

Your simply missing a single span in your CSS. You need to apply the initial opacity to your span as well.

See below:

```css
[class*=subcategory] span {
  background-size: 20px !important;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

[class*=subcategory]:hover span {
  background-size: 20px !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.subcategory1:hover span {
  background-size: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="subcategory1">
  <span style="font-size: 100px; background-image: url(https://designmodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/designmodo-icon.png); background-size: 25px">I am in a mess</span>
</div>
```